# reducing size of widget dynamically?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a widget that looks like this- dynamicallly:

[image]

This is my try, I want to reduce the size dynamically given that I define the initial size of the bigger circle:

```
Row _pagesIndcator(int length) {
  List<Widget> points = <Widget>[];

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    points.add(Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:2.0),
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          height: 8,
          width: 8,
        ),
    ));
  }
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: points,
  );
}
```

I tried this:
`height: 8-i/1,`

but I don't think it's the right way of making it!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Give this a try and let me know if it works, you can play with the values according to your needs.

```
Row _pagesIndicator(int length) {
  List<Widget> list = [];
  list = List.generate(length, (i) {
    return Container(
      width: (length - i) * 10.0 + (i + 1) * 5,
      height: (length - i) * 10.0 + (i + 1) * 5,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
    );
  });

  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: list,
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when the factor (10.0) changes (to 1.0 for example), the size fading direction gets reversed. I think I'll opt-in the equation `height: 8-i/1` but with considering the minus case

Comment: I just used random equation, you can work on it on your own needs, and let me know if you have further issue. Thanks

Comment: I actually thought there's a widget for such case like `AspectRatio`

Comment: Never used that, you can try it and let me know how it worked.

Comment: I updated the code, it is working now for higher values, would you mind accepting the answer now?

Comment: Thanks for trying helping me, but it produces the same problem (change 10.0 to 1.0 for example).. I'm not looking for an equation , I'm looking forward to a robust solution from Flutter framework itself!

Comment: How many items did you enter? And the code, that you posted was showing every dots of equal size, at least my code was able to show you how to do that (not possible in flutter as of now).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191754/discussion-between-mshwf-and-copsonroad).